# Why isn't zsh printf respecting octal notation?

Tags: zsh, printf

```
sh -c 'printf "%d " 024'
bash -c 'printf "%d " 024'
zsh -c 'printf "%d" 024'
```

The above outputs `20 20 24`. Why is zsh not respecting octal notation? Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`zsh` is not a POSIX shell, it was written before the POSIX specification of `sh` was released, took features and syntax from ksh, csh, tcsh, rc and added many of its own. Its syntax is for a large part Korn-like, but that doesn't mean it's fully compatible with the Korn shell. In any case, it's not and never was intended to be a POSIX compliant interpreter for the sh language (at least not in its default mode).

It however has a number of emulation modes (csh, ksh and sh (formerly trying to follow the SysV sh, now following POSIX sh)) that can be used to improve compatibility with other shells and interpret code written for them. That means it can have its own syntax separate from that of sh or any other shell (like csh, rc, fish, perl, python...) and still be able to interpret code written for sh.

If invoked as `sh`, `csh`, or `ksh` (or anything starting with `s` (or `b` for Bourne), `c` or `k`), or in newer versions with `--emulate sh/ksh/csh`, it will enter the corresponding emulation mode, but that's not how you would normally use those. To interpret a `sh` script, you'd run `sh`, not `zsh`.

You'd rather run `emulate sh` within `zsh` to switch the emulation mode to `sh` when wanting to interpret sh code within zsh, and you can also run `emulate sh -c 'some code'` to have `some code` interpreted in `sh` emulation.

So, within `zsh`:

```
emulate sh -c 'printf "%d\n" 024'
```

would run `printf` in a more POSIX way.

As for `printf`, a `printf` utility  first appeared in Research Unix Ninth Edition (from AT&T Research / Bell Labs, not in wide use) circa 1986, to get the same text formatting API as available in C with the `printf` libc function.

While the `C` one takes a format first argument as a pointer to a NUL-delimited array of bytes and extra arguments of different types (pointer, integer, double...), an executable can only take arguments as strings. So to format a number for instance for `%d`, it needs to be given a text representation of a number and convert it back to a binary integer and `printf` converts it back to text for output.

In the [original implementation in V9](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V10/cmd/printf.c), `printf` recognised the same numbers as in the C language (dec `-123`, `+123`, octal `0123`, hex `0x123`, float `1.2e-2`, even `'x'` or `"foo"` (where it's the value of the first character that is used)).

SVR4 (descended from V7) also had a very dumb `printf` utility that just did:

```
        printf(fmt, argv[2], argv[3], argv[4],  argv[5],
                        argv[6], argv[7], argv[8], argv[9],
                        argv[10], argv[11], argv[12], argv[13],
                        argv[14], argv[15], argv[16], argv[17],
                        argv[18], argv[19], argv[20]);
```

So it was only useful for `%s`-type formatting as `printf()` was only given pointers to the string arguments.

POSIX.2 (written in the late 80s behind (mostly-)closed doors and released in 1992 (not freely available then)), specified a `printf` command. As the `echo` utility was very unportable and unreliable, an alternative was much needed. For some reason, they didn't go for `ksh`'s `print` builtin but specified a `printf` utility mostly based on the V9 implementation and with a reference to the C language when it comes to convert strings to numbers.

ksh88, the shell on which the POSIX `sh` specification is based on never had a `printf` builtin (nor did its pdksh clone). It has its own `print` builtin as a reliable alternative to `echo`. A `-f` option for `print` was added in ksh93 though along with a `printf` alias for `print -f`.

In ksh, most builtins or constructs that take numbers as input will accept any arithmetic expression, not just numeric constants. So in ksh93

```
printf '%d\n' '1 + 1'
```

Would print `2`.

And in early versions, `printf '%d\n' 010` would print 10, not 8.

In ksh shell arithmetic expressions, initially, numbers with leading 0s were not considered as octal because in a shell, it's much more common to deal with 0-padded decimal numbers (like in date/time, file names) than it is to deal with octal numbers.

However the POSIX specification did sort of require those to be treated as octal which most shells ignored (as the original implementation of the shell on which the standard was based didn't). However after [that PASC Interpretation Request](https://web.archive.org/web/20000901041136/http://www.pasc.org/interps/unofficial/db/p1003.2/pasc-1003.2-173.html) which made it clearer, most shells started to switch their behaviour (including ksh93, [and `zsh`, though that was reverted](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2000/msg02210.html)), causing much pain.

If you look at the [release history of ksh93](https://github.com/ksh93/ksh/blob/master/src/cmd/ksh93/RELEASE), you'll notice that the handling of 0-prefixed numbers as octal has been on and off. Even today, you'll find that 010 in arithmetic expressions is 8 inside `((...))` or `$((...))`, but 10 in most other places, including `let '...'`, `array[...]`, `[[ ... -eq ... ]]` and... `printf`. `set -o posix` makes it change to 8 in most places, [one notable exception being... `printf` again](https://github.com/ksh93/ksh/issues/326).

Since zsh never claimed to be a POSIX shell, it just [added a new option (`octal_zeroes`)](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2000/msg02211.html) in 2000, enabled in `sh` emulation, but not otherwise.

A `printf` builtin was added later in 2001, [initially using `strtod()`](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2001/msg02610.html) to convert text to numbers so treating numbers with leading 0 as octal, but later changed to accept any arithmetic expression like in ksh93 so subject to the `octal_zeroes` options, and allowing more number formats such as `0b10010`, ksh-style arbitrary based numbers (`12#A001`, `2#10010`...), `1_000_000`...

So, in `zsh`, to pass a number octal to `printf`, the options are:

- emulate `sh` and use leading 0: `emulate sh -c 'printf %d 024'`
- set the `octalzeroes` option: `set -o octalzeroes; printf %d 024`
- same in a local scope only: `(){ set -o localoptions -o octalzeroes; printf %d 024; }` (here in an anonymous function).
- use the `8#oooo` notation which is always recognised: `printf %d '8#24'`
- disable the `printf` builtin, and assume the system's `printf` utility is POSIX compliant in that regard: `disable printf; printf %d 024`.
- Other ways to invoke that standalone `printf`: `command printf %d 024` (not in `sh` emulation), `=printf %d 024` (not in `sh` emulation).

Comment: If I were to vote for a solution to the octal issue, I would propose thatm in the same vein as `0x` and `0b`, we could use the `0o` notation (zero followed by an *o*). That string **is** unique, allows to have octal numbers, and doesn't conflict with decimals that start with a zero. Anyone like the idea ?

Comment: History, interesting as it may be, is, in no way, what should lead the future. Yes, the saying: *Those who forget history are condemned to repeat it"* is correct and valid, but that is a knowledge needed to **avoid** some solutions, not to **build** new solutions. If history were the main path to grow, we should still be using `csh` (the most popular `sh` some time ago). But instead, we have sites like [this one](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) from around 1995. What we need for the future should avoid past errors but should not be limited to use only past solutions.

Comment: Yes, 0o has been suggested several times. See for instance [there](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0085r0.html). One of the objections is that the o/O is easily confused with a 0  there. But in any case, I agree that it's much better than just a 0 prefix. The `8#` prefix from ksh IMO is even better where it can  be used.

Answer (score 1):

Use `command printf ...` to run the standard printf utility. zsh's printf has its own argument interpretations that conflict with the POSIX standard, %d interprets arguments as arithmetic expressions, so you can convert a value from octal with `printf %d '8#24'`.

Answer (score -1):

zsh is not POSIX compliant by default and the deviations are not minor only.

This is a general problem with using zsh.

Try:

```
zsh --emulate sh -c 'printf "%d\n" 024'
```

and it will print 20

But note, this will only work with a recent `zsh` version.

If you like a method that works even with older `zsh` versions, there is a way to do that. Create a file `$HOME/.zshenv` with the following content:

```
if [ -n "$ZSH_EMULATION" ]; then
    emulate "$ZSH_EMULATION"
fi
```

If you have that file, you can call:

```
ZSH_EMULATION=sh zsh -c 'printf "%d\n" 024'
```

and that will work with any version of `zsh`.

BTW: the current text related to `ZSH_EMULATION` has been introduced after a discussion in the comments.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129496/discussion-on-answer-by-schily-why-isnt-zsh-printf-respecting-octal-notation).

Comment: There's no version of `zsh` that has ever used the `ZSH_EMULATION` variable to set the emulation mode. `ZSH_EMULATION=sh zsh -c 'printf "%d\n" 024'` has always printed `24`. To get into `sh` emulation, it's `emulate sh`, and has been seen around 1995. But here, it's only the `octalzeroes` option you need to turn on to get numbers with leading 0s considered as octal in arithmetic expressions (though in general it's not something that you want as it's much more common to deal with 0-padded decimal numbers than octal numbers in shells especially today).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas you are definitely mistaken. Maybe your zsh binary is not compiled as usual. It works for me on Soaris and Linux and I got that from the documentation.

Comment: There is definitely no mention of ZSH_EMULATION in the source or documentation of zsh 5.1.1 which you claim to be using in chat, nor is there in the whole git commit history of zsh. If it does work for you, that must be coming from some 3rd party patch.

Comment: It is most unlikely that Sun did use the same patches as Ubuntu. It is however strange that none of the binaries contains the string `ZSH_EMULATION` and it still works. OK, I found that my ~/.zshenv contains related code. It may be that some automatic copied that to my homedir or that I took that from an advise from the network...

Comment: :-D, seems to be coming from [me](https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg01101.html)!

Comment: If you want to start `zsh` in `zsh` emulation in older versions of `zsh`, beside the obvious `zsh -c 'emulate sh; printf...'`, you just need to invoke `zsh` as `sh` (with sh as its argv[0]), so `ARGV0=sh zsh -c 'printf...'` in zsh or `(exec -a sh zsh -c 'printf...')` in some shells (including recent versions of zsh). But why would you want to run a new invocation of `zsh` in `sh` mode? If that's to run a `sh` script, just use `sh`. Running `zsh` in `sh` mode is otherwise crippling it.

Comment: This unfortunately does not work if you like to test the behavior of `zsh` with `configure` and this was my main purpose when I looked for a feasible method that finally ended in the `ZSH_EMULATION` environment.